I have a 2006 Ford expedition 5.4 liter and when I put it in drive the engine revs up like it's slipping then it catches, but having to repeat process
I have a 2006 Ford expedition 5.4 liter and when I put it in drive the engine revs up like it's slipping but then it catches and I'm on my way ,until I have to make another stop then I have to repeat the steps over again and again and again ,I changed out the transmission filter already ,help
